# Duplicated attribute in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model NewsFeedItem like this:

```
public class NewsFeedItem {
    @PropertyName("like_number")
    protected int likeCount = 0;

    @PropertyName("time")
    protected long timestamp;

    @PropertyName("ownerUid")
    protected String ownerUid;

    @PropertyName("ownerUsername")
    protected String ownerUsername;

    @PropertyName("comments")
    protected List<Comment> comments;

    @PropertyName("likes")
    protected Set<String> likes; //Store user uid of who like this status

    public NewsFeedItem() {

    }

    protected NewsFeedItem(int likeCount, long timestamp, String ownerUid, String ownerUsername, List<Comment> comments, Set<String> likes) {
        this.ownerUid = ownerUid;
        this.ownerUsername = ownerUsername;
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public int getLikeCount() {
        return likeCount;
    }

    public void setLikeCount(int likeCount) {
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getOwnerUid() {
        return ownerUid;
    }

    public void setOwnerUid(String ownerUid) {
        this.ownerUid = ownerUid;
    }

    public String getOwnerUsername() {
        return ownerUsername;
    }

    public void setOwnerUsername(String ownerUsername) {
        this.ownerUsername = ownerUsername;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Set<String> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Set<String> likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }
}
```

Then I subclass it in Status model:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Status extends NewsFeedItem {
    @PropertyName("content")
    protected String content;

    @PropertyName("photo")
    protected String photoUrl;

    public Status() {
        //Required for deserialize
    }

    public Status(String ownerUid, String ownerUsername, String content, String photoUrl, int likeCount, long timestamp, List<Comment> comments, Set<String> likes) {
        super(likeCount, timestamp, ownerUid, ownerUsername, comments, likes);
        this.content = content;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

The code pushing data to Firebase:

```
@Override
public void pushStatusToFirebase(Status status) {
    database.getReference("status").push().setValue(status);
}
```

But when I push to Firebase the `like_number` and `likeCount` display together like this:

[image]

It also happen to all of my model class. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to make all your fields `public` and not protected as they are now, otherwise the annotations will not work.

Now, the annotation takes into account both the field name as well as the getter/setter names to serialize. You have this problem because the fields as well as the getter/setters were getting serialized and that's why are resulting duplicates.

So use the annotation on the field name which are public and ignore the getter/setters. This will solve your problem. Your data will be properly serialized with the property name you want and there will be no duplicates as well.

Comment: What do you mean ignore the getter/setters? I need to use @Exclude on get/set?

Answer (score 1):

Try to mark with `@PropertyName` your getters instead of fields. Another option that may be working - mark with `@Exclude` your getters.